# Keys pressing too quickly in a game

Tags: keyboard

I have recently reinstalled Ubuntu 16.04. However, I have come across an extremely annoying issue where some applications see one press as two, making it virtually unusable. It only happens in particular programs, and resetting keyboard layout did not work.

Thanks.

EDIT: I can confirm the keyboard is not at fault; I tested it on my Chromebook and it was fine. "Fine" meaning that everything is working as it should.

I tried changing the USB connection. Nothing changed. No settings in the BIOS. With keyboard tests everything looks fine.

And an onscreen keyboard still doesn't work.

SDL ISSUE! FIXED! It just needed downgrading to 2.0.3.

Comment: Are you sure it's not a hardware problem?

Comment: Would help if you specified what applications exactly exhibit this problem for you.

Comment: I am pretty certain hardware is fine. I can't test it on anything else because I don't have a second keyboard. I found it mostly in SuperTux (I tried several versions) and to a lesser degree terminal, but that doesn't bother me too much as it doesn't affect usability.

Comment: Close voters! This question has [been answered](http://askubuntu.com/a/886291/225694).

Answer (score 1):

These adjustments are made via <kbd>System Settings</kbd><kbd>Keyboard</kbd> as shown below:

[image: repeat]

The Delay controls how long before the key repeats and the Speed controls the speed of the repetition.

If for some unknown reason that doesn't resolve your issue, there are also typically  keyboard repeat rate adjustments available in your BIOS

Comment: That didn't seem to fix it for me; in-game it is exactly the same.

Comment: Replace your keyboard

Comment: I concur with Elder Geek. If this symptom persists despite this setting it's very likely a faulty (or dirty) key press sensor. I had keys like that in the past and either cleaned the key or replaced the keyboard.

Comment: A mod of this game, Cheeseman, however, has no such issue.

Comment: My testing indicates that Super Tux doesn't have this issue either (at least not with my decade old keyboard)

Comment: I was on the same system and the same operating system with no problems until I reinstalled.

Comment: And I don't believe it is just a "dirty key" as other keys seem to be affected, and it makes gameplay almost impossible.

Comment: You have my apologies, but with all due respect, beliefs don't interest me near as much as facts, and as this question has been closed as "Unclear what you are asking" it's unlikely to get any further attention until you expend the effort required to [edit] it following the guidelines [here](http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I can confirm the keyboard is not at fault; I tested it on my Chromebook and it was fine.

Comment: Oddly, I still don't see an [edit] that might trigger reopening this question allowing for other answers. I can't provide you with better advice than that at this point. It's never my intent to be unclear, but perhaps [this will help](http://www.yourdictionary.com/edit) you understand what is required.

Comment: I did edit it, but I have no idea what you want changed. if you tell me what information you want, I can supply it.

Comment: Can you think of anything useful to know that you haven't provided? One example might be what type of keyboard you are using (make/model/connection) and if USB whether you get the same results using a different USB port on the same machine. Another example might be how you tested it on your Chromebook and what "fine" means in this context. A third example might be what you found when you looked for obstructions in or damage to connectors. I'm sure you can think of other related bits of information that might be useful as well.  Did you [edit] which "some applications" are affected?

Comment: I've even tried an onscreen keybaord and that didn't work, eliminating the possibility of hardware issues.

Comment: SDL issue. FIXED!

Comment: If you've solved you problem please write a [detailed answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer) so that others with the same issue can benefit from your experience. Thank you!

Comment: I can't because this is closed.

Comment: @brmbrmcar It's closed as unclear what you are [asking](http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) Please [edit] your question to provide more detail and request that it be reopened. Since you have already solved your problem that particular task should be easier for you to accomplish now.